# How do I specify lastObject of an NSArray with dot notation?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I specify lastObject of an NSArray with dot notation ?

For instance:

```
@"myArray.lastObject"
```

is wrong.

But I need to express a path with dot notation in my code.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using it in a string?

Comment: I need it for a sort descriptor: NSSortDescriptor *rankSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"managedItems.lastObject.Order" ascending:YES];

Comment: Create the array as you want it - take value at index [[array count]-1] and append string

Comment: managedItems has only 1 object, which contains the order value I need to order the main array.

Comment: @EliGregory do you mean @"myArray.[[array count]-1]" ?

Comment: Well, that specifically wouldn't work put in code. The idea is to creating a pointer to the last object in an array and modifying it. What sorts of objects are going in this array? NSStrings? Post some code and i'll see if I can post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray* foo = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"bar"];
id baz = foo.lastObject;
```

The above works fine for me.

So, if you are using lastObject to get a key for sorting, you do something like the below.  Note that dot notation does not work unless the compiler knows what type the object is and lastObject returns id, so you'll either have to do a typecast to get `Order` or use the normal syntax.

```
NSSortDescriptor *rankSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: ((MyObject*)managedItems.lastObject).Order 
                                                                   ascending: YES];
```

Or (better in my opinion)

```
NSSortDescriptor *rankSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: [[managedItems lastObject] Order] 
                                                                   ascending: YES];
```